# ' ; ' expected when trying to create a prototype function call

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to create a simple Animal class with a constructor and a prototype function to return an Animal's name and description.

So far, I created the constructor for the class:

```
class Animal {
    Animal(name, description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

But when I try to create an Animal prototype and call a function to return the Animal's name and description...

```
Animal.prototype.message = function() {
    return this.name " + has the following description: " + this.description;
}
```

...Visual Studio Code highlights the periods in `Animal.prototype.message()` and tells me `';' expected`.

I've been at this for an hour now and I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but regardless I would like to know what I'm doing incorrectly. Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: fixed code typos.

Comment: `Animal.prototype.message() = function {` should be `Animal.prototype.message = function () {` You have your `()` in the wrong spot.

Comment: ```Animal.prototype.message() = function {``` Move the ```()``` from ```message``` to ```function```.

Comment: The constructor of a class is `constructor(...)`, not `Animal(...)`. The brackets of a function always go behind the `function()`.

Comment: and don't forget the `+` after `return this.name...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of issues here.

1. In your class, you do not have a constructor (`Animal` should be `constructor`)
2. You are using prototype to add a function to your class. Why not just do it the right way (...the es6+ way)

I would be the goofy error you're receiving is because of the "constructor" setup (using `Animal` instead of `constructor`) or it's because you're doing

`Animal.prototype.message() = function { ... }` (should be `Animal.prototype.message() = function() { ... }`)

Example:

```js
class Animal {
    constructor(name, description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }
    message() {
        return `${this.name} has the following description:  ${this.description}`;
    }
}

const animal = new Animal('liger', 'a lion and a tiger');
const message = animal.message();
console.log(message);
```

Comment: Can I create the prototype method within the class? Or does it have to be outside the class?

Comment: Create it inside the class like I did. `.prototype` is the old way of doing things. `.prototype` still has it's use, but you're making a class from scratch in which case you're supposed to define your methods within the class (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: I see, that makes sense now. Thank you for your response.